# Unable to reorder "your communities" with touch

Tags: bug, user-interface, top-bar, stack-exchange-button, communities-list

I have a Windows tablet. I am accessing SE via IE 11 (metro) and using the touch screen.

To reproduce:

1. Go to the SE menu in the SE bar.
2. Select `edit` next to Your Communities.
3. Attempt to use the drag handles with your finger.

Failure.

---

Additionally, on **all platforms**, if you close the SE menu while in the editing UI, then reopen the SE menu, the editing UI persists. I think it should be cancelled on close.

Comment: Could somebody with an iPad and/or Android tablet confirm/deny this issue?

Comment: Repro on iOS, but I wouldn't say it's a big enough problem to throw dev resources at.

Comment: It seems that this issue persists for more than 8 years since it was reported. I am able to reproduce it on my Android phone with the Chrome browser.